# How do non-ideal inductors behave in a circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

I cannot comprehend how
can we break a seemingly non-ideal choke coil into just a pure resistor and inductor in series according to the following solution of a question.

[image: Question and solution]

Considering the data in the question (all given values are R.M.S values),krichoff's voltage law is seemingly violated,is the question or solution incorrect or am i missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'violation' of Kirchhoff's rules is presumably the summation of the $V_\mathrm{coil}$ $300$V AC drop on the lossy inductor with the  $V_{R}$ $200$V AC drop on the resistor
to produce a $400$V result.

AC in series adds according to the rules for adding sine waves,
not for adding DC voltage drops.   The  phase of two sine waves
can be matched ($300$ V AC plus $200$ V AC yields $500$ V AC), or
opposed ($300$ V AC plus $200$ V AC yields $100$ V AC) or anything
that results from the vector addition of two gyrators.

Mathematically, one adds
$$300 \cdot \sqrt {2} \cdot e^{j(\omega t + {\phi_1})} + 200 \cdot \sqrt {2} \cdot e^{j(\omega t+ {\phi_2})} = 400 \cdot \sqrt {2}  \cdot e^{j\omega t }$$
to find the absolute value of the complex result.   The $400$ V AC result phase, of course, is an input phase, which we define as zero.

Measured values will be the real part only, of the gyrator complex function.   The $\sqrt2$ is from RMS to peak value conversion.

Comment: Instead of $exp(jwt+phi)$ it should be $exp(j(wt+phi))$.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch -yes, you're right of course.   Edited to correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your concise and quick response,however if the phases of the voltages aren't equal wouldn't that imply that a voltage drop of 300V and 200V cannot occur together.

Comment: @Blz The voltage of 300V occurs instantaneously twice in the sine wave that has 300Vrms measure.   The instant at which the other value is 200V is presumably different due to the two phases, phi_1 and phi_2, being different.

Comment: @Whit3rd if that's the case then in the provided solution we have implicitly assumed that the rms voltages of the components would occur at the same time that too at thr time when the source voltage is at its rms value, isn't this incorrect.

Comment: @Blz The 'time when the source voltage is at its RMS value' identifies two times when the AC waveform crosses that value, which is just a kind of average, not a voltage that could be useful in a Kirchoff sum.   The Kirchoff sum must be taken for each term added, and for the result, on every part of the cycle.   That's why gyrators are the useful model.